# Solve $x=\pm\frac{y'}{\sqrt{(y')^2+1}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$x=\pm\frac{y'}{\sqrt{(y')^2+1}}$$

$$x=\pm\frac{y'}{\sqrt{(y')^2+1}}$$

$$x^2=\frac{(y')^2}{{(y')^2+1}}$$

$$x^2(y')^2+x^2=(y')^2$$

$$(y')^2[x^2-1]=-x^2$$

$$(y')^2=\frac{-x^2}{x^2-1}$$

$$y'=\pm \sqrt{\frac{-x^2}{x^2-1}}$$

Have I got it wrong? as there is no ODE

Comment: it looks correct to me,why didn't you proceed?

Comment: It meant to be solve as ODE and I just got a simple integral

Answer (score 4):

It looks alright.

You're mistaken in saying there's no ODE. Every line in your posting is just an ODE.

From where you left off I'd go on to say
$$
\int\pm\sqrt{\frac{-x^2}{x^2-1}}\,dx = \int\pm\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}} = \int\pm \frac x {\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx = \int\pm \frac {du}{2\sqrt{u}} = \pm \sqrt u + C
$$
$$
= \pm \sqrt{1-x^2} + C.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution

> $$y'=\pm \sqrt {\frac{-x^2}{x^2-1}} \\ \frac{dy}{dx} =\pm \frac x {\sqrt {1-x^2}} \\ \int dy = \pm \int \frac x {\sqrt {1-x^2}} \, dx =\pm \frac 1 2 \int \frac {d(1-x^2)}{\sqrt{ 1-x^2}}=\pm \sqrt {1-x^2} \\ y=\pm \sqrt{1-x^2} +C$$

Comment: What's wrong with the answer? please show my mistake.It is  second  time somebody  downvotes without any explanation.

Comment: Sometimes down-votes here are completely irrational and sometimes they are dishonest.